# How to read EOF and parse line by line using awk

Tags: awk

I have a few txt files in my folder, which contain a large amount of data. Now I have to create a file by reading one line from every file at a time. The new file should look like this:

```
foldername-file1.line1
foldername-file2.line1
fodlername-file3.line1
...then repeat the cycle
fodlername-file1.line2
fodlername-file2.lin2
fodlernam-file3.line2

fodlername-file1.line3
fodlername-file2.line3
fodlername-file3.line3
```

Until the end of the files I have to concatenate the files.

I tried with sed but it is giving poor performance as I have lot of data.

```
counter=0
line=$(awk 'NR==n' n=$counter $filename)
echo $line >> $2
```

I am incrementing the counter in a loop. I don't know how to check for the end of file.

with the paste command I am not able to append the folder name with every string and extra lines are appended when files has different number of input lines

I just solved this problem by myself and just want to share the solution.
I used a script in which first append required string to all lines and then runs below command to read all the strings
paste -d '\n' files* |awk '{if(length($0)>0) {print $0}}'

Comment: @TomFenech I just made minor correction to the suggested edit, I don't think the OP question is the right place for these sort of comments, that's what MSE is for. Plus your edit actually changes too much in my opinion. The OP refers to sed which you have now removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) command and set the delimiter to newline.

```
paste -d'\n' file*
```

Here is how it will work:

Lets say you have the following files:

```
$ head f*
==> f1 <==
1
2
3
4
5

==> f2 <==
11
12
13
14
15

==> f3 <==
21
22
23
24
25
```

```
$ paste -d'\n' f*
1
11
21
2
12
22
3
13
23
4
14
24
5
15
25
```

Comment: Thanks jaypal for your help. This works fine. Only thing is each file is located in separate folders, as : 
INPUTFILES/FOLDER1/file1, 
INPUTFILES/FOLDER2/file2, 
INPUTFILES/FOLDER3/file3. All these files are under same main folder (INPUTFILES).   
I have to append the foldername is to each line.
the final output should be:
FOLDER1-line1 from file1
FOLDER2-line1 from file2
FOLDER3-line1 from file3

Sorry I didn't mention this earlier, b'cos I thought I can handle appending the folder name, but the with paste command I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: @user3666144 You can use `find` in conjunction. Something like `paste -d'\n' $(find . -type f -printf "%h/%f ")`. This requires GNU `find` though.

Comment: Thanks once again. 
The given command is awesome, but it has few issues. It is not giving required o/p. There was duplication of data and few lines are like this "foldername"-FNR!=EOF. 
I am allowed to use a script, it need not be in a single command.

Comment: How to avoid adding empty lines to output file when we have different sizes of files.
like file1 has 3 lines and file 2 has 10 lines. In the output the paste command is adding extra 7 lines and there are less lines first file. So the output file has 3+10+7white lines

Comment: @user3666144 You seem to have an awful lot of new requirements. I would recommend closing this question and opening a new one where you can list all your requirements clearly.